# Meteor collection using existing database

Tags: node.js, meteor, content-management-system

I am new to meteor and could not find a way to load existing database into meteor.

Here is the scenario. I have an existing remote database with collection 'analytics' that is being used by a mobile application to record users' data. For Meteor side, I am building an admin panel to load the analytics data for visualization. I successfully connects to the remote database however I am not able to display any data in Meteor.

Here is my code:

```
Analytics = new Mongo.Collection('analytics');
console.log(Analytics.find().fetch());
```

It shows empty array even though the collection is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it.

**OPTION 1**

Setting `MONGO_URL` environment variable like this

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://<remote-url>:<db-port</<db-name>
```

Example,

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/db
```

This way all collections you create using `new Mongo.Collection('<collection-name>');` will use remote database.

**OPTION 2**

If you want to use only `Analaytics` collection from remote database then

```js
var driver = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://localhost:27017"); 
// Or If you have oplog URL
// var driver = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://localhost:27017", { oplogUrl: <oplog-url-string-here> }); 

Analytics = new Mongo.Collection('analytics', { _driver: driver });
```

Answer (score 0):

Befor start Meteor, you need set MONGO_URL

Look at [this](http://basvdijk.com/meteor-with-external-mongodb/) article.

After that, you need autopublish package or correct pub/sub.